# Where do I find the reviews summary file?

Tags: php, template, review

I need to change the reviews ratings on the category and product pages to a custom review star system from a third party.

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0 and I have the code:

`<div class="ruk_rating_snippet" data-sku="<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>" data-store="my-store-ltd"></div>`

I am stuck on how to find the files and what to overwrite on my custom copy?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 2):

Go to System -> COnfiguration -> Advanced => Developer -> Template path hints.

select Yes and save.

It will show the exact template file path of the magento.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't have 'Template path hints' in the developer section in 1.9.1.0?

Comment: @Bertie it is not on a global level so you will have to switch from the default view on the configuration page